Добавление данных со связью Many-To-Many WPF
Есть связь многим ко многим: Ученик и Группа, в одной группе может быть несколько учеников, так и ученик может числиться в нескольких группах
Подскажите, РАДИ БОГА, как с помощью такой связи добавлять данные?
Работаю в WPF через Entity FrameWork

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core - могу посоветовать этот туториал. Конечно, это ASP.NET, а не WPF. Но зато там хорошо показано, как отображать в UI связанные данные и как их обновлять. Смотрите разделы Read related data, Update related data. Естественно, если у вас нет опыта, то нужно весь туториал пройти.

Если хотите получить действительно рабочий хороший ответ, то укажите точные версии .NET и EF.

Два этого в EF Core делает конфигурация для трёх таблицу - двух основных и третей дополнительной. Представим следующее:
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Для связи между этими таблицами нужно создать третью таблицу, которая будет иметь связь один-ко-многим по отношению к каждой таблице:
public class GroupStudents
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }

    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

И добавляем ссылку на эту таблицу к предыдущим классам:
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<GroupStudents> Groups = new List<GroupStudents>();
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GroupStudents> Students = new List<GroupStudents>();
}

Последний этап конфигурация. Напомню, что в Entity Framework Core можно настроить связь между таблицами только на одной из таблиц. В нашем случае, делаем конфигурацию для GroupStudents:
public class GroupStudentsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GroupStudents>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GroupStudents> builder)
    {
        // PK в это таблице является уникальная связка FK на связанные таблицы.
        // Иными словами, вы не сможете добавить одного и того самого студента в одну групу
        builder.ToTable("Groups students").HasKey(x => new { x.GroupId, x.StudentId });

        builder.HasOne<Grop>(x => x.Group)
            .WithMany(group => group.Students)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId);

        builder.HasOne<Student>(x => x.Student)
            .WithMany(student=> student.Groups)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StudentId);
    }

}

Всё.
Ресурсы для изучения:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx


Это, конечно, хорошо. Но как связанные данные отобразить в GUI? И позволить юзеру комфортно их вводить, удалять, редактировать.

@AlexanderPetrov, это уже совсем другой вопрос. Как сделать GUI? Ну, как сделаете, так и будет) Вопрос вообще состоит в том, что бы настроить связь много ко многим, а не как юзеру будет удобно с этим работать. Вообще GUI это уже ваша задача, главное, что вам нужно, это при добавлении студента в группу, вы будете делать новую запись в таблице GroupStudents связываю студента с группой

У автора в заголовке "Many-To-Many WPF".

@AlexanderPetrov, Подскажите, РАДИ БОГА, как с помощью такой связи добавлять данные? Работаю в WPF через Entity FrameWork. Ни слова об GUI. Или я не верно дал ответ? Это вам не позволит добавлять данные? Или мне лучше нужно было написать что-то в роде: "Ну вот кнопочку добавьте и скриптик привяжите к ней, и буде всё у вас работать, только ещё напишите правильно"

Вы не видите слово WPF?

@AlexanderPetrov, океееееей. Если я спрошу, как мне сделать то же самое на asp.net mvc, вы мне распишете всё от БД до вёрстки да ещё и по паттернах?

Влезу в спор. Как минимум, в вопросе вижу "Есть связь ... как добавлять данные?", в ответе хоть что либо сказано про то, как это делать? Я лично вижу ответ на "Как сделать связь", ее настройку, но не ее использование. Также этот вопрос про WPF, который имеет свои тонкости, а именно механизм привязок, и да, если вопрос имеет конкретную метку, которая вносит свои коррективы, то эти коррективы должны быть затронуты в ответе, ибо повторю, привязки... Отвечу на вопрос выше (хоть адресован не мне) - да, я напишу простую верстку и покажу как пользоваться правильно всем этим, ибо это требуется по ТЗ.

@EvgeniyZ, объективно, спасибо

В комментарии под вопросом я дал ссылку на туториал ASP.NET MVC + EF, где именно работа с many-to-many подробно расписана. Было бы здорово дать автору подобный же туториал по WPF + EF. Если подобное вменяемое руководство есть где-то в сети - дайте ссылку, кто знает. Если кто-то напишет хороший ответ, я назначу награду.
